# Combining column of courses with similar ID's

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bridge table that helps me track the employees and the mandatory courses they have to take and keep track of when the do it.

```
completed_training [employee_id^, course_id^, date_completed]
employees [id^, first_name, last_name]
training_courses [course_id, course_name]

^foreign_key
```

data in the completed_training bridge

```
|employee_id | course_id | date
| 1          | 1         | null
| 1          | 2         | null
```

I have a while loop that goes through and builds out a table and duplicates the employee id with the course_id. How do I combine the course_id onto one  so I can group the employee_id?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Is your goal something like `employee_id: 1, course_id: 1, 2`? Can yo show us what your desired result table looks like?

Comment: You are correct with your response right not looks like this 

employee 1 course 1
employee 1 course 2

sorry for the sparatic brain....trying to figure this out

Comment: @Scooter Isn't that just what's in the `completed_training` table?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, here's my guess at what you want, and how you can get it:

```
|employee_id | course_ids |
| 1          | 1,2        |
```

To get this result, your select statement will be similar, but with a little extra. First, you will use a `GROUP BY` phrase to tell MySQL to bunch together results with the same `employee_id`. Then you will use a group function to tell the query how to combine the results for the ids column.

Presumably right now you have something like

```
SELECT * from completed_training
```

You might be joining that with other stuff as well, without your actual query I can't know that. But that query will yield your example output above.

You can modify that query to bunch the data together based on employee_id:

```
SELECT * from completed_training GROUP BY employee_id
```

That will give you one row per employee, but which `course_id` you get is undefined. But now that you are grouping the result, you can use one of the [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) to combine the course ids together.

```
SELECT employee_id, GROUP_CONCAT(course_id SEPARATOR ',') from completed_training GROUP BY employee_id
```

That will create a result with the course_ids combined into a single column.